# Generate a master table based on a unique identifier with columns for the data from each table/worksheet

Tags: excel, database, merge

I am currently working in Excel but I am willing to consider solutions in (free) database software. The data I have is organized by time period, one worksheet for each period. The worksheets all have the same column structure.
Here is an example of the data from the 2017-Q1 worksheet:

```
| Time Period | Product ID | Prod. Category ID | Product Scale |
| 2017 - Q1   | 0012345678 | 012345            | 3             |
| 2017 - Q1   | 0023456789 | 012345            | 1             |
| 2017 - Q1   | 0033333588 | 022235            | 3             |
| 2017 - Q1   | 0123333333 | 022235            | 1             |
```

Here is an example of the data from the 2017-Q2 worksheet:

```
| Time Period | Product ID | Prod. Category ID | Product Scale |
| 2017 - Q2   | 0012345678 | 012345            | 5             |
| 2017 - Q2   | 0033333588 | 022235            | 7             |
| 2017 - Q2   | 0123333333 | 025444            | 5             |
| 2017 - Q2   | 0145555578 | 025444            | 1             |
```

The things that I am particularly focused on are:

1. Product ID 0023456789 does not appear in 2017-Q2, so the corresponding column in the master worksheet should show something (it could be blank, it could be NULL, it could be N/A, it doesn't matter as long as it is always the same.) The same thing needs to happen when a Product ID first appears in a later time period, the time periods before that should have the same N/A (or NULL, or blank, or whatever) This means that in order to form the master worksheet, I need to make a consolidated list of all of the Product IDs from all of the time periods, since not all of the Product IDs are present in every time period.
2. Product ID 0123333333 changed Prod. Category ID, so I need to always pull at least the Prod. Category ID column and the Product Scale column for each time period, just to be sure if it has changed or not.

I want to generate a master worksheet as follows (abbreviating column names just for space constraints here in this website):

```
| Product ID | 2017-Q1PCID | 2017-Q1 PS | 2017-Q2 PCID | 2017-Q2 PS |
| 0012345678 | 012345      | 3          | 012345       | 5          |
| 0023456789 | 012345      | 1          | N/A          | N/A        |
| 0033333588 | 022235      | 3          | 022235       | 7          |
| 0123333333 | 022235      | 1          | 025444       | 5          |
| 0145555578 | N/A         | N/A        | 025444       | 1          |
```

I have 12 different time period worksheets, so the master worksheet would need to first make a master list of unique Product IDs and then have 24 additional columns, because there are 2 columns for each time period (one column for the Product Category ID and another for the Product Scale ID, for that time period.) Furthermore, I should mention that each time period worksheet has 8,000-12,000 Product ID records, so ideally the solution should be able to handle thousands of rows fairly quickly.

Comment: Why does the Prod.CategoryID need to change each month? Is it not constant for all months for a given ProductID?  Instead of 24 addl columns, don't we need just 12 for each ProductID?  I do see that your data does have a Category difference on one case, but it just seems odd to re-Categorize during the year.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR : use index() match() .

Assuming the table 1 is located at "Sheet1" and the "Product ID" in the last table is located in cell A1, put this in B2 :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('2017-Q1'!C:C,MATCH(A2,'2017-Q1'!B:B,0)),"")
```

and in C2 :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('2017-Q1'!D:D,MATCH(A2,'2017-Q1'!B:B,0)),"")
```

and drag downwards.

Idea : 'load' the answer if the Product ID is matched in the source sheet, and put blank if no Product ID match is found.

Hope it helps. (: